# Wi-Fi passwords are forgotten

Tags: wi-fi, bugs

My nexus 4 is not storing new Wi-Fi passwords. Each time I want to connect to a previous connected Wi-Fi I have to re-enter the password.

I found that in `Settings > Backup & Restore` everything is checked but `Backup account - No account is currently storing backed up data` is in gray and i can't do anything about it.
In `Settings > accounts > google` i have everything sync but Movies & TV and photos.

I'm running kit Kat, not rooted.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting (forgetting) the wireless connection first.  Sometimes security information (WPA/WPA2) related to the connection is cached and is no longer relevant.  When the security information doesn't match, the connection can be shaky.

If this is a pervasive issue (all wireless connections) delete (forget) all wireless connections, and open the app in app manager and delete all cached data.

Comment: It happens with all connections, I will clear cache but first I have to back up all working connections